# identify last object within mergeMap

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, angularfire

i want to merge my ranking entity with my member entity in ionic4/angular7.

what i actually do is:

```
this.rankingObs = this.rankingService.getAll().pipe(
  mergeMap(ranking => { 
    ranking.forEach(rank => {
      this.membersService.get(rank.key).subscribe(member => {
        rank.firstName = member.firstName;
        rank.lastName = member.lastName;
        rank.keyName = member.key;
      })
    });
  return ranking;
  }),
).subscribe((merged) => {
  let ranking = merged as RankingModelAll;
  this.rankingmodel.push(ranking);

   //***
   //CAN'T BE CORRECT HERE :( i only want to sort at last and also set the preloadingDone at Last
  this.rankingmodel = this.rankingmodel.sort((n1,n2) => {
    if(n1.points < n2.points) {
      return 1;
    }
    if(n1.points > n2.points) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  this.preloadingDone = true;
  // ****
});
```

merging my members names into the ranking model, but how can i identify the last run of my merged entity to set my preloadingDone flag to true and do the sorting of top rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have few comments about your code.

1. Nested subscribe is not very good practice. You should flatten it.
2. Use `subscribe(next, error, complete)` *complete* handler to set your flag preloadingDone to done
3. In your case I would use insert into sorted array, instead of sorting whole array at the end.

Take a look at snippet bellow:

```
    const orderedInsert = compareFn => (array, item) => {/** need to code this :( */};

const insetRank = orderedInsert((n1,n2) => {
        // your compare fn
        if(n1.points < n2.points) {
          return 1;
        }
        if(n1.points > n2.points) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      }
);

this.rankingObs = this.rankingService.getAll().pipe(
  mergeMap(ranking => from(ranking))
  mergeMap(rank =>this.membersService.get(rank.key).pipe(map(member => ({
      ...rank,
      ...member 
  }))
).subscribe((rankMerged:RankingModelAll) => 
  insetRank(this.rankingmodel, rankMerged), 
  e => console.log(e), 
  () => {
    this.preloadingDone = true;
    console.log('Done')
 });
```

Comment: thank you for the tipps, this are pretty cool examples.. but one more question, how can i flatten this instead of joining the data? if i put the names into the ranking collection, the old data would be used if a user is changing his name :(

Comment: one more question, there is a second mergeMap in the pipe, i dont understand what this is and my vscode says this wont work :(

Comment: @HaraldWiesinger, second merge operator is a spread operator  https://mzl.la/2GbFCdo. In this case it merges 2 object into 1. (similar to object assign). Your vscode complain because my code missing 2 closing brackets. `...member  }))))`

Comment: `but one more question, how can I flatten this instead of joining the data?` - I didn't . really get what you mean, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: thanks for your answer! you told me that nesting isnt a good practice in this case. so actually i have a node with my ranking where the id to the user is with in. so i think with flattening you mean, instead of putting the userid there, you want me to put the firstname and lastname there, or i am wrong? ;)

Comment: @Harald Wiesinger, sorry I should of explain it better. When I said nesting I ment `nesting subscribe`. In your case `subscribe` inside of `mergeMap` is a bad practice.  I suggested to use only 1 subscribe, take a look at my example.

Comment: hmm its still not working, is it possible that a , is missing between the two mergeMaps? but if i set the , syntax check marks the rank.key within the 2nd mergemap and says that property key is not available for type 'never'

Comment: and in ionic-cli is the error: Property 'key' does not exist on type 'never'.
, error TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.

Comment: Take look at code https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tzhmsb?file=index.ts, it's very close to your example

Answer (score 1):

the return value in merge map should be an observable. In the above code, ranking will be returned before the subscription completes, so it will be working with rank data that hasn't been updated yet.

I think what you want might be something like:

```
this.rankingObs = this.rankingService.getAll().pipe(
  mergeMap(ranking => {
    // an array of all observables which will return the merged rank and member data
    const ranksWithMembers = ranking.map(rank=>{
        return this.memberService.get(rank.key).pipe(
            map(member=>{
                return {
                    ...rank, 
                    firstName: member.firstName, 
                    lastName: member.lastName,
                    keyName: member.key,
                }
            })
        )
    })
    // does not emit until all observables in array emit. Emits all results.
    return forkJoin(ranksWithMembers)
  }),
).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, i tried this, but it seems the emit doesnt work :( the subscribe is never reached

Comment: try putting `tap(member=>console.log('member', member))` before the `map` to see if it gets that far

Comment: is it possible that there is no emit, because of the realmtimedatabase of firebase?

Comment: Add error handler to a subscribe, probably this's type somewhere or server responses with error. then it will get to subscribe error handler only.